# Why do I have to load a PHP array to a variable before fetching an element?

Tags: php

Why do I have to load a PHP array into a variable before I access its elements?

Why can't I access the elements directly from the result of a function call?

e.g. This works:

```
$foo = "This is a variable I'm going to split/explode";
$bar = explode(' ', $foo);
echo $bar[1];
```

But this doesn't:

```
$foo = "This is a variable I'm going to split/explode";
echo explode(' ', $foo)[1];
```

Comment: It does work from PHP 5.4 and above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because array dereferencing only became available in PHP 5.4. If you want to do that you'll need to upgrade to at least that version.

Comment: They just didn't have that feature. New versions introduce new functionality. PHP 5.4 introduced array dereferencing. The ones before it did not.

Comment: Thanks - Looks like I have version 5.3.3 - found by inserting phpinfo() in my code.  Looks like it wasn't implemented before because they were worried about memory leaks - http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html